# Is there any way to hide html tags while echoing string with 'gettext'?

Tags: php, internationalization, translation, gettext

I wonder if there is a way to hide html tags when echoing a string with php gettext function.

This is what I got and I want to strip html tags from string before putting them to .po file.

```
<?=_('You must be logged in to add a link.<br />
If you already have a account, 
<a href="#" name="Log In">click here</a> to log in or 
<a href="#" name="Register">join us</a> now!'); ?>
```

This puts string to .po file like this:

```
You must be logged in to add a link.<br />  If you already have a account, <a href="#" name="Log In">click here</a> to log in or <a href="#" name="Register">join us</a> now!
```

Translations of my website will be publicly editable (with Pootle) so I wonder is there any way to hide html tags from public? is there anything like this:

```
You must be logged in to add a link. If you already have a account, click here to log in or join us now!
```

Comment: if you store html in a variable and strip_tags() from it where necessary - wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real way to hide them and be able to reinsert them after the translation, you could use character position map, but after the translation the character length to the html tags would change.

If you absolutely want to avoid html tags what you could do is to leave the breaks in and convert them to new lines if needed for transalators then use individual translations for text inside html tags for example;

```
<?=_('You must be logged in to add a link.<br /> If you already have a account,') ?>
<a href="#" name="Log In"><?= _('click here') ?></a> <?= _('to log in or') ?>
```

'); ?>